# How do you order by Greatest number in linq

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to print products in order of quantity.The product with a bigger total should be first.

What am I missing here as it's NOT printing in order or total

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var products=new List<Product>
                         {
                             new Product {Name = "Apple", Total = 5},
                             new Product {Name = "Pear", Total = 10}
                         };

        var productsByGreatestQuantity = products.OrderBy(x => x.Total);

        foreach (var product in productsByGreatestQuantity)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(product.Name);
        }
        System.Console.Read();
    }
}

public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: don't you need OrderByDescending keyword?

Comment: @MR if you want find the product with greatest total.How do you do it?

Comment: products.OrderByDescending(x => x.Total).SelectFirstOrEmpty()

Comment: @user231465 pls accept any of the answer, all the answer seems to be prompt.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var data = products.OrderByDescending(x => x.Total);
```

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
var productsByGreatestQuantity = products.OrderBy(x => x.Total);
```

to:

```
var productsByGreatestQuantity = products.OrderByDescending(x => x.Total);
```